# Proof that the first pivots in matrices $A, B$ will be in the same column.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, proof-writing

This is a part of the proof that the reduced row echelon form of a matrix $M$ is unique, so please consider that when answering this question.

Now what I need to prove is this:

> Suppose matrices $A, B$ are reduced row echelon form matrices of an $m\times n$ matrix $M$. Show that the first pivots of $A$ and $B$ appear in the same column.

Here is my stab:

Take the first non-zero column of $M$. No set or row operations can transform a non-zero column into an all-zero column. Therefore, since $A, B$ are in RREF, they will appear as leading 1's in both of the matrices in the same column.

This sounds too informal to me, so I was wondering if this is formal enough for a proof, and if not, how can the following intuitive reasoning be formalized?

Answer (score 0):

While the defintion of reduced row echelon form (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form)) says that this form is unique, independend of the algorithm by which it is obtained, the uniquness statement only makes sense if the rref of $M$ is somehow related to $A$.

One obvious option to do this is to say $A$ is obtained from $M$ by Gauss-Jordan elimination. In that case uniqueness is obvious (a simple proof by induction, if you insist on a formal proof), since $A$ is obtained from $M$ by a unique reproducible recipe.

A more interesting question is which other relations exist between $M$ and $A$ (which is, unfortunately, not discussed on the wiki page).